# axios not retrieving cookie

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

Hey I am having an issue where when I am running the server and app locally there is no issue but when each is pushed to their respective servers the app does not return the cookie. Does anyone know how to get around this?

server:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  next();
});
```

react:

```
const request = axios.post(`${url}/api/login`, {
      email,
      password,
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: { crossDomain: true, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
    .then(response => response.data);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this. I used:

Server:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://myapp.com',
  })
);
```

React:

```
export function loginUser({ email, password }) {
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  const request = axios
    .post(`${url}/api/login`, {
      email,
      password,
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: { crossDomain: true, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
    .then(response => response.data);

  return {
    type: 'USER_LOGIN',
    payload: request,
  };
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Works even without the `headers` option.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use defaults `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true`

It's a known [bug](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/191) with axios

Comment: Thank you but where would I put that? Within the request?

Comment: Just put it before the request